# Reorder Data before it is displayed in view

Tags: zend-framework2

I use [ZeTheme](https://github.com/ZendExperts/ZeTheme) to allow users to select different themes. In one theme I would like to display the data that comes from the controller in a different way, like reordering and grouping artifacts.

I know the controller should handle such things, but in this case it would be only for this theme, another theme might have something completely different and the rest of the themes should stay as they are. It should be a drop-in solution provided by the theme itself.

The options that came into my mind are:

- custom `Controller`
- custom `RenderStrategy`
- custom `ViewHelper`
- **EDIT:** hook into some `Event` (didn't find out which would be applicable yet)

for each theme.

Is there something I missed? What would be the best choice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the `ViewHelper` approach. Basically you'd be doing something like this:

#### Conifiguration

```
'view_helpers' => [
    'factories' => [
        'collectionRenderer' => 'My\View\Helper\CollectionRendererFactory'
    ]
]
```

#### The Factory

```
<?php
namespace My\View\Helper;

use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;

class CollectionRendererFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $sl)
    {
        $realSl = $sl->getServiceLocator();

        $userTheme = // get access to the current theme, session, config, user-db, whatever

        return new CollectionRenderer($userTheme);
    }
}
```

#### The ViewHelper

```
<?php
namespace My\View\Helper;

use Zend\View\Helper\AbstractHelper;

class CollectionRenderer extends AbstractHelper
{
    protected $theme;

    public function __construct($userTheme = 'default-theme')
    {
        $this->theme = $userTheme;
    }

    public function __invoke($collection)
    {
        return $this->getView()->render(
            'path/to/collection/renderer/' . $this->theme,
            ['collection' => $collection]
        );
    }
}
```

#### Example Views

```
// module/path/to/collection/renderer/default-theme.phtml
<h2>Stuff in list</h2>
<ul>
<?php foreach ($this->collection as $entry) : ?>
     <li><?= $entry->getName();?></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Then depending on the selected theme it could also be a table

```
// module/path/to/collection/renderer/super-mega-theme.phtml
<h2>Stuff in table</h2>
<table>
<?php foreach ($this->collection as $entry) : ?>
     <tr><td><?= $entry->getName();?></td></tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

#### The normal view

```
echo $this->collectionRenderer($collectionData);
```

Inside the views you'd be able to do stuff with the collection as well, like re-ordering, etc...

Comment: Nice solution. Let's see if something else comes in the next 6 days.

Answer (score 0):

How about you store the type of theme the user is currently using in via sessions? And control the data via a simple if condition that checks if the theme is the one that needs data reordering:

```
use Zend\Session\Container;


// serves as identifier, you can access this is other controllers by doing this line again and the namespace you used.
$container = new Container('namespace'); 

// Setter
$container->themeName = 'theme name';

// on a separate controller this is how you check
$container = new Container('namespace');
if ($container->themeName == "theme name") {
    // do reordering stuffs

}
```

Comment: It should be decoupled from the controller. I would have to add a new condition for every theme that needs another structure. This will blow up the controller quite much. I looking for something that can run after the controller did his job (fetch, convert and prepare the data) and the display in the view. Such that it can just be put together with the theme.